# Stuck with asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand `async/await` in C#. Let's assume I have simple API endpoint
which will fetch data from database by its id with EfCore `FirstOrDefault` extension method like below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var user= userService.GetById(id);
     
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Do I need to make this method asynchronous to reach better performance using EfCore `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and declaring async method in `UserService` interface like so?

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
        {
            var user= await userService.GetByIdAsync(id);
     
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Does this change make sense? If yes or no, how can I check it?

Comment: It's still synchronous because you're waiting, but you can't do concurrent calls in EF.

Comment: So it only makes sense if I do some time consuming operation in-between ```userService.GetByIdAsync``` and ```return Ok(user)``` and await response like ```return Ok(await user);```?

Comment: @GHDevOps The `GetByIdAsync` call is `await`'ed, so the call is asynchronous. While awaiting the `GetByIdAsync` result, the thread can do other stuff.

Comment: @RaymondChen in this case I do not do any operation after ```await```ing ```GetByIdAsync``` method just returning result, so it will not affect the result, yes?

Comment: What `await` does (roughly) is let your code step away from the thread on which it's executing while the operation completes.  Once the operation completes, your code will continue as if nothing happened (well, depending on your environment, your context may be a little changed).  No nothing happens between the await and the return, as @RaymondChen mentions, it's anything but synchronous.  Read up on how this all works on Stephen Cleary's blog (this is a good start: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: @Flydog57 I have read a lot about ```async/await```, but when it comes to practice it gets confusing. So, just from my example in the question, does it make sense to make it asynchronous? And what do you mean by ```nothing happens between the await and the return```?

Comment: What that means is that the function does not continue beyond the `await`. But because it's all asynchronous, it's possible for there to be re-entry: the function could be executed a second time concurrently. Effectively it compiles down to something like `Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) { return userService.GetByIdAsync(id).ContinueWith(Get2); }` and another function `Task<IActionResult> Get2(UserObject user) { return Task.FromResult(Ok(user)); }` in other words it's split into separate functions before and after the `await`. That's a vast simplification, but you should get the idea.

Comment: `async` will get you better performance, because it means your thread is free to go off and handle another request.

Comment: You're freeing up your mouse...all your doing

Answer (score 2):

> Does this change make sense?

Yes, in the general sense. Asynchrony on web servers is all about scalability; by freeing up threads that would otherwise just be waiting on I/O, your server can handle more requests with fewer threads.

However, this isn't a blanket "make everything asynchronous and your server will be golden" statement. For example, if you have a single database as your backend (i.e., an MSSQL server instead of Azure SQL), **and** if most/all of your requests hit the database in some way, then the database server is probably going to be your scalability bottleneck rather than your web server. And in that case, you can put in a lot of work adding `async` to your whole project just to discover that you scaled something that didn't need scaling.

In general, I recommend `async` for new code (since it's almost as easy as synchronous code these days); but whether it's worth it to modernize old code is a question only you can answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sir. What books, courses, resources you prefer to get clear knowledge and understanding in TPL, async/await, concurrency, multithreading?

Comment: I have [a blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) and [a book](https://stephencleary.com/book/). There are others, too, but I haven't had time to evaluate them all. In general, I recommend resources that focus on newer tech over older tech; e.g., an understanding of threads is necessary, but an understanding of `Thread` is almost useless.

Comment: I generally recommend starting with my [intro to async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then [async best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).